# Minmax theorem for optimization over isometries and states

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, unitarity, optimization, trace-distance

I have the following minmax problem and I am wondering if the order of the minimum and maximum can be interchanged and if yes, why?

Let $\|\cdot\|_1$ be the trace norm defined as $\|\rho\|_1 = \text{Tr}(\sqrt{\rho^\dagger \rho})$. This gives us a distance measure between quantum states i.e. $\|\rho - \sigma\|_1$. Consider Hilbert spaces $A,B,E$ and $R$.

The optimization problem I have is

$$\max\limits_{\phi_{AR}} \min_{V_{E\rightarrow E}}\|(I_A\otimes V_{E\rightarrow E})(U_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} - (U'_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} \|_1$$

where $U_{A\rightarrow BE}, U'_{A\rightarrow BE}, V_{E\rightarrow E}$ are all isometries and $\phi_{AR}$ is a pure state. So my optimization is over the set of isometries and pure states neither of which is a convex set. However, note that the optimizations involved are on different Hilbert spaces.

Is it true or false that
$$\max\limits_{\phi_{AR}} \min_{V_{E\rightarrow E}}\|(I_A\otimes V_{E\rightarrow E})(U_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} - (U'_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} \|_1 = \min_{V_{E\rightarrow E}}\max\limits_{\phi_{AR}} \|(I_A\otimes V_{E\rightarrow E})(U_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} - (U'_{A\rightarrow BE}\otimes I_R)\phi_{AR} \|_1$$

and if true, what is the justification? I am aware that I can always upper bound the LHS with the RHS using the [maxmin inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality).